# Sorting search results with multiple facets

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet

I'm using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7

I am trying to find a way to sort search results with 2 facets without using custom code or having it affect performance speed.

In this case, I have some blog posts that I need to be sorted both by date and by a computed index field I created called Featured, I want the Featured posts to always appear first, and the search results in general to be sorted by date.

I was able to do this by setting the facet to sort by date, and adding the sort by featured in the search result scope.. however, I have noticed that adding any kind of sorting inside the scope causes a big performance issue, as the search results are significantly slower to load once sorting is added.

What I need to know is if there's a way to implement this without having it affect the performance speed so much? and possibly without having to make custom code?

Comment: It's probably not possible without writing custom code but as far as I remember the Search Service (and the Ordering Service which is injected there) supports multiple facets to sort with. But I need to confirm that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the implementation and the `o` param accepts multiple sortings. You can pass there something like that: `Title,Ascending|MyField,Ascending`. This means that the results will be sorted by `Title` field in ascending direction and then by `MyField` field also in ascending direction.

But at the moment there is no way to pass two sorting params at once from the UI so that you would need to extend the front-end part.